# Ionic Android Strange routing when physical key is pressed [Honeywell CK65]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic6

We are developing Ionic android app and we are having a strange problem with Honeywell CK65 device, to be more specific with device physical keyboard.

If the app is being used only by touch, without device physical keyboard, the app is working correctly.
But when physical keyboard is used, example

- when ENTER key is pressed, it should navigate to another page but the remain freeze and it appends on the bottom page the previous page.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow configure the app to use the devices keyboard. My guess is that you need to create a custom plugin to call the device's built in keyboard and map those keys to a function.

Comment: Keyboard key is working and action attach is being called correctly, but after the action is done the app freeze and previous page is being append under the current page.

Comment: Whats does the console show when button is being clicked?

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the problem using ionic ion-router-outlet instead of angular router-outlet